# s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration deletes existing events

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3, notifications

I am trying to add Event Notification in s3 bucket using put-bucking-notification API. It is overwriting the existing event notification with the newly submitted event. What I want to achieve is to add a new event notification to the existing list of events.

I am able to do that from amazon console. I found that amazon is using an undocumented API PutAllBucketNotification to implement this.

Is it possible to do the same using boto3/java ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the answer. The logic is to first get the existing set of event notifications and then add the new notification to the array and then submit the entire set using put API

Comment: Just discovered this in the Node SDK. I think I speak for everyone when I say that this work around is awful. Good luck to the person with concurrent deployments!

Comment: @RyanSmith how did you solve the problem? Can you please share?

Comment: This answer is the only solution to the problem, unfortunately it's terrible for concurrent deployments, hopefully someone at AWS spots this and implements an API with a better solution. I don't really understand why this API was designed like this since most of the other APIs don't behave in this way.

Comment: Yes! It pissed me off too because it took me a lot of time to realize what is happening!